# Editor Tracking setting on a FGDB preventing data display in QGIS

Tags: qgis, file-geodatabase, data-management, compatibility

I have a File Geodatabase containing a polyline feature class. I can drag this into QGIS (3.0.0) and view the data in a read-only format. This is fine, for the purposes of the majority of users of this data they simply need to be able to reference the data.

This data, however, will be subject to some editing by multiple users in an Arc environment. As such, I want to have Editor Tracking enabled to keep a record of changes that are occurring. However, once Editor Tracking has been enabled, this data no longer displays in QGIS. I can still drag the layer in, but the attribute table is empty, and nothing shows in the project view screen.

What is the exact nature of the change that occurs to a feature class with Editor Tracking enabled that might be the cause of this behaviour?

What can I do with this feature class so that I am still able to keep track of edits whilst simultaneously providing read-only access to users in a QGIS environment?